# Did ancient Yogis float in the air and what is the method to do it?

Tags: history, philosophy, yoga, siddhi, yogi

"**In Ancient India Yogis used to float in the Air**" I am not sure about this statement but I heard people who have more concentration (possibly through Yoga) floated wherever they wanted.

My question is, **is it true that ancient Yogis floated in the Air?** If Yes, what are the methods used to float in the air?

Comment: Read Laws of miracles chapter in Autobiography of a Yogi.

Comment: "Autobiography of a Yogi" - https://www.ananda.org/autobiography/  this is the one?

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I am having a doubt and not sure if it's feasible or not. If I got any answer can I post it here to my question.

Comment: May be that was Astral Projection or Lucid dreaming.

Comment: I believe this is a factual, scientific question. Thus answers should use evidence to justify their claims. An ideal answer would present evidence that yogis did float and a discussion of the physical principles, or refute it due to a lack of evidence or evidence showing illusion techniques likely to have been used.

Comment: No.  No, they didn't -- not physically, at least.

Comment: Among the 8 great powers (Ashta Maha Siddhi) - lahima, the power to become light (as a feather, say) can be gained. Ashtanga yoga is one way to attain these siddhis.

Comment: @CCCV, it goes against everything I believe to be true about physics, but how can you be so sure? Can you provide an actual answer with refuting evidence?

Comment: @Octopus There is no evidence that this is physically possible. You are quoting from a book that is 100s of years old written by scribes that probably weren't actually there when it happened.  If you are trying to be factual and scientific then this is nothing to do with Hinduism, it's it scientific.  If you know anyone today, who can 'float' under controlled conditions (i.e. no trickery) there is at least $1M waiting for you here: http://web.randi.org/

Comment: @Octopus, when someone asserts an idea that is incompatible with knowledge that we've gained via science, the burden of proof is on that person to substantiate their assertion.  I cannot disprove that there is, for example, no [Invisible Pink Unicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_Pink_Unicorn)... but that's not my burden.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First we should know our body is not just physical body, but has [five sheaths](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3075/3500) (Pancha Kosha). What we see externally is Annamaya Kosha (food sheath). After death we shed Annamaya kosha and jiva with other four koshas (Sookshma Sareera or Subtle body) go to other realms, hell or heaven depending of Karma and Sukshma Sareera takes new physical body (rebirth) as mentioned in [Chandogya Upanishad](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5489/3500).

Yogis who know they are pure Consciousness (Atman) will never be subjected to laws of Space and Time and to laws of other four sheaths. They are no longer subjected to laws of physical body.

Yogananda explains the reason for all Siddhis or miracles in his book **[Autobiography of a Yogi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobiography_of_a_Yogi)** (published in 1946).

**Bhaduri Mahasaya** was one such levitating sage described in chapter 7 of same book.

[image]

> "Indeed it is true! He has lived indoors for the past twenty years. He
>   slightly relaxes his self-imposed rule at the times of our holy
>   festivals, when he goes as far as his front sidewalk! The beggars
>   gather there, because Saint Bhaduri is known for his tender heart."
>
> "How does he remain in the air, defying the law of gravitation?" (asks Upendra)
>
> (Yagananda/Mukunda says) "A yogi's body loses its grossness after use of certain pranayamas.
>   Then it will levitate or hop about like a leaping frog. Even saints
>   who do not practice a formal yoga  have been known to levitate
>   during a state of intense devotion to God."

Yogananda further says their consciousness becomes mass free and they see whole cosmos as undifferentiated mass of light. Read **Chapter 30** completely to get an overview of laws of miracles. I quote a few words of Yogananda to explain it in brief.

> The consciousness of a perfected yogi is effortlessly identified, not
>   with a narrow body, but with the universal structure. **Gravitation,
>   whether the "force" of Newton or the Einsteinian "manifestation of
>   inertia," is powerless to compel a master to exhibit the property of
>   "weight" which is the distinguishing gravitational condition of all
>   material objects.** He who knows himself as the omnipresent Spirit is
>   subject no longer to the rigidities of a body in time and space. Their
>   imprisoning "rings-pass-not" have yielded to the solvent: "I am He."
>
> A yogi who through perfect meditation has merged his consciousness
>   with the Creator perceives the cosmical essence as light; to him there
>   is no difference between the light rays composing water and the light
>   rays composing land. Free from matter-consciousness, free from the
>   three dimensions of space and the fourth dimension of time, a master
>   transfers his body of light with equal ease over the light rays of
>   earth, water, fire, or air. **Long concentration on the liberating
>   spiritual eye has enabled the yogi to destroy all delusions concerning
>   matter and its gravitational weight; thenceforth he sees the universe
>   as an essentially undifferentiated mass of light.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60911/discussion-on-answer-by-the-destroyer-did-ancient-yogis-float-in-the-air-and-wha).

Answer (score 17):

By practicing Yoga and pranayama (control of prana vayu) a Yogi can float in the air, walk in air. This is called Vayu-Siddhi or mastery over air. It can be achieved in the third stage of pranayama sadhana.

From [Shiva Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Samhita):

> In the first stage of pranayama the body of the Yogi begins to
>   prespire. When it prespires, he should rub it well, otherwise the body
>   of the Yogi loses its dhatu (humours).
>
> [image]
>
> .........
>
> In the second stage, there takes place the trembling of the body. In
>   the third, jumping about like a frog; **and when the practice becomes
>   greater, the adepts walk in the air.**
>
> [image]
>
> ........
>
> When the Yogi, though remaining in Padmasana, **can rise in the air and
>   leave the ground, then know he has gained Vayu-Siddhi** (success over
>   air), which destroys the darkness of the world.

There are many siddhis (perfections) that are obtained by the adept Yogi and among which floating (or walking ) in the air is one.

> > The Yogi acquires the following powers:- Vakya siddhi (prophecy),
> >     transporting himself everywhere at will (Kamachari), clairvoyance
> >     (duradrishti), clairaudience (durasruti), subtle-sight (sukshma
> >     drishti) and the power of entering another's body (parakayapravesha),
> >     turning base metals into gold them with his excrements and urine and
> >     the power of becoming invisible and **lastly, moving in the air**.

Also, among the six chakras, [the Anahata Chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anahata) is ruled by the Vayu Tattva
 . An adept Yogi, by contemplating on this chakra & by mastering it, can
 achieve mastery over vayu or air. Then he can walk in air
 successfully.

> In the heart, is the 4th chakra, the Anahata. It has twelve
>   petals....He who always contemplates on this lotus of the heart is
>   eagerly desired by celestial maidens.....
>
> He gets immeasuarable knowledge, knows the past, present and future
>   time ; has clairaudience, clairvoyance **and can walk in air whenever he
>   likes.**
>
> [image]
>
> .....
>
> He sees the adepts and the Goddesses known as Yoginis; obtains the
>   power known as Khechari, and conquers all who move in the air.

..............

> [image]
>
> .......
>
> He contemplates daily on the Banalinga [[which is situated in the
>   Anahata Chakra]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18837/what-are-the-three-shivalingas-itara-bana-and-swayambhu-mentioned-in-some-ag) **undoubtedly obtains the perfections called Khechari
>   (moving in air)** and Bhuchari (going at will all over the world).

So, a highly adept Yogi can float or walk on air.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60945/discussion-on-answer-by-rickross-did-ancient-yogis-float-in-the-air-and-what-is).

Comment: @sv. "is mixing physical phenomenon with pseudoscience? "   What??  The sankrit  used is "*samsara dwandha vinasini**..

Comment: @sv. Mastering vayu or mastering the heart chakra results in more than one siddhis. What it says is that darkness of the world (IMO ignorance) is also removed once the anahata chakra is mastered. Floating in air is yet another accomplishment that is obtained upon activating the same chakra.

Comment: @sv No of the Yogi. Yogi destroys his ignorance after obtaining the vayu siddhi. But people who get to be in touch with a true Yogi can get their own ignorance removed as well. That's one of the reasons a Yogi walks in this world in disguise. He doesn't want people to come to him.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, a Yogi can float in the air by using yogic power. Their are [eight type of siddhis](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/what-is-ashta-siddhi-and-nav-nidhi) also known as `ashta aishwarya` can be attained by yoga as described in [Shrimada Bhagavatam, Chapter 11.15](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/15). Yogi can float in water or hang in air by `Laghima`.

> aṇimā mahimā mūrter
>
> laghimā prāptir indriyaiḥ
>
> prākāmyaṁ śruta-dṛṣṭeṣu
>
> śakti-preraṇam īśitā (11.15.4)
>
> guṇeṣv asaṅgo vaśitā
>
> yat-kāmas tad avasyati
>
> etā me siddhayaḥ saumya
>
> aṣṭāv autpattikā matāḥ (11.15.5)
>
> Among the eight primary mystic perfections, the three by which one transforms one’s own body are aṇimā, becoming smaller than the smallest; mahimā, becoming greater than the greatest; and **laghimā, becoming lighter than the lightest**. Through the perfection of prāpti one acquires whatever one desires, and through prākāmya-siddhi one experiences any enjoyable object, either in this world or the next. Through īśitā-siddhi one can manipulate the subpotencies of māyā, and through the controlling potency called vaśitā-siddhi one is unimpeded by the three modes of nature. One who has acquired kāmāvasāyitā-siddhi can obtain anything from anywhere, to the highest possible limit. My dear gentle Uddhava, these eight mystic perfections are considered to be naturally existing and unexcelled within this world.

In purport it is given that:

> through laghimā one becomes so light that one can ride on the sun’s rays into the sun planet

Vayu Purana, Chapter 13 also mention that hanging and floating is possible through `Laghima`.

> अणिमा लघिमा चैव महिमा प्रातिरेव च। प्राकाम्यं चैव सर्वत्र ईशित्वं चैव सर्वतः॥३॥
>
> वशित्वमथ सर्वत्र यत्र कामावसायिता। तच्चापि विविधं ज्ञेयमैश्वर्यं सार्वकामिकम्।।४।।
>
> Anima (the superhuman power) of becoming as small as an atom, one of the eight powers or Siddhis, atomic nature Laghima (the Supernatural power of assuming excessive lightness at will), Mahima (power of increasing size at will), Prapti (power of obtaining everything), Prakamya (irresistible will) and Isitva (superiority) everywhere and all over, Vasitva (the supernatural power of subduing to one's own will) everywhere, wherein (abides) Kamavasdyita (suppression of passions) that even should be considered as varied one, the supremacy of all cherished ends (fulfilment).
>
> लम्बनं प्लवनं योगे रूपमस्य सदा भवेत्। शीघ्रगं सर्वभूतेषु द्वितीयं तत्पदं स्मृतम्।।१२।।
>
> Hanging and floating in Yoga may be its perennial form. The Swift movement normed may be its second pre-requisite among all the beings.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, In Ancient India Yogis Floated in the Air**, here is the [explanation](http://www.hinduismfacts.org/hindu-science/) what I got:

> In Hindu mythologies some Yogis possess the power of floating in the air while meditating. This can be explained with the phenomenon of superconductivity. This is a possible scientific explanation.
>
> Superconductivity is a phenomenon in which the electrical resistance of certain materials becomes exactly zero, below a characteristic temperature, usually well below 0 degrees Celcius. For example, some cuprate-perovskite ceramic materials become superconductors at -183 degrees Celcius. When the **material becomes superconductor, magnetic lines do not pass through them and they float in the air.** This can be easily demonstrated in the lab using liquid nitrogen and the superconductor material. The same principle applies to the body of the Yogi.

**Saint Dnyaneshwar experience:**

> In **Dnyaneshwari**, written by **Saint Dnyaneshwar**, he has described his experience of what happens when **Kundalini Shakti arises in the body**. He has mentioned that it feels like Kundalini power drinks all the blood and eats up all the flesh in your body and your body becomes very, very cold. After some time, it again regenerates everything and your body becomes as fresh as a newborn. 
>   It is quite possible that when the **temperature of Yogi's body decreases, it reaches to a point where Yogi's body becomes a superconductor and hence, the gravitational lines do not pass through his body and he floats in the air.** Though, there is no proof for this but it is quite possible. Hence, it is not a superstition that Yogis float in the air. So Yogis who floating in the air was based on some science knowledge and it moves from generations to generations as a practice/tradition.

Note: If someone got any other Principles or Scientific explanation please don't hesitate to share your answers.

Comment: Please avoid preformatted text in your answers. Use italics or bold instead.It doesn't look nice.

Comment: Avoid Scientic speculation in your answers. first paragraph was purely scientific explanation.

Comment: So, you are suggesting that Yogi somehow managed to make their bodies -183 degrees Celsius and survived?  About 100 degrees colder than ever occurs anywhere on the earth, in India, which is not known for its cold climate?

Comment: _Helicopters are a phenomenon in which spinning rotors provide lift and enable the vehicle to fly and hover. The same principle applies to the body of the Yogi._ Oh look, I can arbitrarily relate something completely distinct to the subject matter too, to make it sound scientific!

Comment: _"material becomes superconductor, magnetic lines do not pass through them and they float in the air."_ No... Superconductors are typically metals, and they don't float.  some materials are Bose-Einstein Condensates (liquids) and they don't float either, though they are able to climb up the sides of containing vessels.   So, No proof, not possible.

Comment: @Neil, that's why we need to know what are the techniques (with Yoga) Yogis used to maintain certain body temperatures which help for body Float in Air.

Comment: @Samthere  Helicaptor -Motors, Human - Organs. may be both are same functional quality's when comes to float in the air?

Comment: @Baldrickk "Superconductors are typically metals, and they don't float" are you sure? So then how Air crafts, space ships float in air, don't say because of Fuel what we used help to maintain everybody knows. Exactly same which is invisible force can lift Human body when they are in Meditation & Yoga (majority world accept Yoga which helps to control our energy) If we try hard one day we might float in the air? No imaginary :p

Comment: @CR241 the only aircraft that float are hot air balloons. They do this by heating the air inside them so that it is of a lower density than the surrounding air, the higher density air around it pushes the balloon upwards. Blimps/airships are almost as light but require thrust from engines to lift them. Planes use the thrust from their engines to provide motion and airflow, Bernoulli's principle (again to do with air density) and (mostly) deflection of the air by the wings push planes into the sky.  Helicopters are all thrust from their rotors...

Comment: ... displacing air, rockets are all thrust from their engines, throwing their exhaust downwards to push themselves upwards (and then sideways to get into orbit) and vehicles in orbit are not floating. Indeed they are in perpetual freefall. They are constantly experiencing acceleration towards the planet, but it is perpendicular to their motion (so doesn't slow them, it just turns them).  All of these forces are evident, and the human body can't produce enough thrust to lift itself from the ground and is orders of magnitude too dense to float in air (hold your hand out in front of you...

Comment: ... subtract the weight of your hand from what you can feel. The force pushing on you hand now is the weight of all the air above your hand, all the way to space combined pushing down. You would need to be lighter than that.)  In fact, the only one of the above that a human can do unassisted is to remain in orbit, given that something else gets you there first (and even then you will slow and fall back due to the minimal but still existant atmosphere slowing you)

Comment: I wonder why nobody has seen the 23km long Large Hadron Collider rise from the earth and float in air, given that it contains what is probably the largest number AND the most powerful superconducting magnets in our planet?

Comment: By the way, let me let the story straigth: 1) some material acts as superconductors, and the writer does not know what that means but they do float under unclear circumstances 2) someone says that when you drink some stuff you feel much colder, maybe 200degrees below your normal temperature 3) the person who just dropped 200 degrees below normal temperature may change his chemical composition so to become a superconductor? And that proves it?!? Beautiful. If I knew it was so easy to prove stuff, I would never wasted my time on so many physics books

Answer (score 3):

Just to add more - A perfect self realized being who has achieved **Jagadānanda**, after knowing he is none other than God & uniting individual consciousness with universal consciousness, not only he can float in air rather he can do anything what he wants. He becomes Omniscient, omnipresent, omnipotence etc, by **recognizing** his true nature.

> Just as all knowability, etc., in respect of the body occurs when it is pervaded by that spanda principle, even so when the yogi is established in his essential Self, **he will have omniscience, omnipotence etc. everywhere**. Spanda Karika 3.7.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "what is the method used to float in the air?" You could move it under the question as a comment...btw, if a yogi is omniscient & omnipotent what is the need for him to float in the air? Why not just sit on the ground? Or why not float all the time?

Comment: @sv. Omnipotence includes ability of floating inherently.  Yes, a true Yogi rarely display their Siddhis.

Comment: @sv This answer first part - Yes they could float.  Regarding your other questions, Do you think if Someone can play cricket, he should play all the times or not play at all?

Comment: @Aghori Cricketing professionals play cricket *most of the time* for a living. I'm not a professional so I only play sometimes for pleasure. "he can do anything what he wants" - I guess most questions on this site can be answered with a blanket statement like that. E.g., Q: "I've heard some yogis visited Pluto or Center of Milky Way and came back. How exactly is this possible?" A: "Simple: he can do anything what he wants"

Comment: @sv. You couldn't relate the cricket analogy with your questions. And regarding others, Gautam Buddha actually went Brahmāloka & came back according to Buddhism.

Comment: @sv. Yes, nothing wrong to answer with such blanket statement with proper citation.

Comment: @sv. I think this answer is absolutely fine.  The question is basically asking "How can one obtain Laghima Siddhi" and the answer given is "Here is how to obtain all Siddhis, Laghima or otherwise."

Answer (score 2):

By the rise of Kundalini a Yogi with attainment of a disease-free spiritual state.. either as a Siddhi or by any means arriving at a Turiya Avastha feels *subjectively* that he is weightless. He is not at all lying about his feeling of his own weightless state.

But a physical spring balance measuring weights would not *objectively* record any weight change on the Earth. All physical bodies lose part of force of attraction /weight in Space ... far away from influence of heavy planets ...anyone floats in a spaceship.

Adi Shankara notes ( that might sound ego-central to many,) that Avidya is subjective but not objective.

Answer (score 1):

**what is the method used to float in the air?**

As per Patañjala Yogasutras, III.40 is by samyam on udana vayu until mastery

> udana jayat jala panka kantaka adisu asangah utkrantih cha
>
> By the mastery over udana, the upward flowing prana vayu, there is a
>   cessation of contact with mud, water, thorns, and other such objects,
>   and there ensues the rising or levitation of the body.

and here you have multiple translation (some number this sutra as III.39)

http://yogasutrastudy.info/2017/02/10/sutra-3-39/

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it true that ancient Yogis floated?

No, there is no empirical evidence to prove it. Floating mid-air (without external physical assistance of some sort) requires bending the laws of nature as we know it. Many people attempt to do this (without any assistance) but in vain and this is what Vivekananda [said](http://belurmath.org/complete_works_of_swami_vivekananda/volume_5/interviews/miracles.htm) when questioned on the truthfulness of these levitation claims:

> Swami Vivekananda was questioned concerning the truthfulness of the
>   marvelous stories of the performance of wonderful feats of conjuring,
>   **levitation**, suspended animation, and the like in India.
>
> Vivekananda said:
>
> > **We do not believe in miracles at all** but that apparently strange
> >     things may be accomplished under the operation of natural laws. There
> >     is a vast amount of literature in India on these subjects, and the
> >     people there have made a study of these things.
> >
> > Thought-reading and the foretelling of events are successfully
> >     practiced by the Hathayogis.
> >
> > **As to levitation, I have never seen anyone overcome gravitation and
> >     rise by will into the air**, but I have seen many who were trying to do
> >     so. They read books published on the subject and spend years trying to
> >     accomplish the feat. Some of them in their efforts nearly starve
> >     themselves and become so thin that if one presses his finger upon
> >     their stomachs he can actually feel the spine.
> >
> > Some of these Hathayogis live to a great age.

EDIT:

#### What is the method used to "float" in the air?

Here's an example of how some [so-called yogis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Pullavar) accomplish this "feat." You can read the [full article](http://gdurl.com/wa9R) (PDF) published in the Illustrated London News (Saturday, 6 June 1936), [here](http://gdurl.com/wa9R). (Courtesy: [The British Newspaper Archive](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/))

[image]

[image]

No explanation is provided as to why the yogi ([Subbayah Pullavar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Pullavar)) sets up a tent before and after the  act. Why does the yogi use a stick if not for support? Why is his stick covered in cloth? Why is the yogi himself covered in excessive clothing?

Despite the author's and photographer's assurances of "total absence of any tricking", the whole act has trickery written all over it.

Comment: " there is no empirical evidence to prove it. Floating mid-air (without external physical assistance of some sort) requires bending the laws of nature as we know it. " There no source provided for this statement. Swami Vivekanda is saying his experiences and what he said  won't substantiate your above claim.

Comment: @TheDestroyer 'what he said won't substantiate your above claim' - it does.  He said 'We do not believe in miracles at all' - so levitation without any assistance is a miracle and not possible according to current laws of physics which is exactly why someone asked him that question in the interview. If Vivekananda wanted the interviewer to really believe in this 'levitating miracle' maybe he should have demonstrated it in the interview. But he didn't which means he had his doubts on its authenticity.

Comment: @TheDestroyer At least he should have quoted his own translation of Raja-yoga and Pranayama stuff, from [here](http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_1/raja-yoga/raja-yoga_in_brief.htm): "In the lowest kind of Pranayama there is perspiration, in the medium kind, quivering of the body, and *in the highest Pranayama levitation of the body* and influx of great bliss."

Comment: **No explanation is provided as to why the yogi (Subbayah Pullavar) sets up a tent before and after the act.** [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwvYkRzpq4g) . But I'm only pointin to some posible answer. I'm not saying that was what happen, and definitivly I'm not saying is not posible.

Comment: @Indra Yes, I already know how it's done. There are plenty of YouTube videos that explain the trick. But we are not allowed to use scientific explanation in answers on this site. 'I'm not saying it's not possible' - without empirical evidence, we can claim whatever we want.

Comment: @sv my point with comment was to show some fake ways of doing it in the context of your answer, just as a complement.  With _'I'm not saying it's not possible'_ I'm just stating that this comment is not my answer, I'm not saying levitation is possible, nor impossible, here on comments. You can take my comment just as off topic . My real answer to levitation is [just up here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24154/13188)