# Has Shiva Linga worship been diluted over time from the real to the unreal?

Tags: shiva-lingam

What do the ancient writings say about worshiping Shiva Linga.

Is the phenominal Shiva linga that is worshipped today a true representation of the God head or is the the long forgotten subtle Shiva  linga within the man of the Golden age the true vehicle of love that when stimulated unites in bliss the temporal with the eternal ?

Comment: Shiva Lingas exist in our body too. See this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18837/what-are-the-three-shivalingas-itara-bana-and-swayambhu-mentioned-in-some-ag

Comment: Thanx Rickross I will check it out.

Comment: Too many questions make the question unclear. Please limit your question to a single topic.

Comment: Sorry guys the questions were put only to deepen your thinking.

Comment: Please visit [ask] and [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/5212). It will give a basic idea how questions should be asked.

Comment: Sarvabhouma and co have deleted multiple distinct questions as requested.

Answer (score 4):

A report on an address given by Swami Vivekananda says (*Complete Works*, V4, section *Translations: Prose*, heading *The Paris Congress of the History of Religions* - http://www.advaitaashrama.org/cw/content.php):

> At the Congress, Mr. Gustav Oppert, a German Pandit, read a paper on the origin of the Shâlagrâma-Shilâ. He traced the origin of the Shalagrama worship to that of the emblem of the female generative principle. According to him, the Shiva-Linga is the phallic emblem of the male and the Shalagrama of the female generative principle. And thus he wanted to establish that the worship of the Shiva-Linga and that of the Shalagrama — both are but the component parts of the worship of Linga and Yoni! The Swami repudiated the above two views and said that though he had heard of such ridiculous explanations about the Shiva-Linga, the other theory of the Shalagrama-Shila was quite new and strange, and seemed groundless to him.
>
> The Swami said that the worship of the Shiva-Linga originated from the famous hymn in the Atharva-Veda Samhitâ sung in praise of the Yupa-Stambha, the sacrificial post. In that hymn a description is found of the beginningless and endless Stambha or Skambha, and it is shown that the said Skambha is put in place of the eternal Brahman. As afterwards the Yajna (sacrificial) fire, its smoke, ashes, and flames, the Soma plant, and the ox that used to carry on its back the wood for the Vedic sacrifice gave place to the conceptions of the brightness of Shiva's body, his tawny matted-hair, his blue throat, and the riding on the bull of the Shiva, and so on — just so, the Yupa-Skambha gave place in time to the Shiva-Linga, and was deified to the high Devahood of Shri Shankara. In the Atharva-Veda Samhita, the sacrificial cakes are also extolled along with the attributes of the Brahman.
>
> In the Linga Purâna, the same hymn is expanded in the shape of stories, meant to establish the glory of the great Stambha and the superiority of Mahâdeva.
>
> Again, there is another fact to be considered. The Buddhists used to erect memorial topes consecrated to the memory of Buddha; and the very poor, who were unable to build big monuments, used to express their devotion to him by dedicating miniature substitutes for them. Similar instances are still seen in the case of Hindu temples in Varanasi and other sacred places of India where those, who cannot afford to build temples, dedicate very small temple-like constructions instead. So it might be quite probable that during the period of Buddhistic ascendancy, the rich Hindus, in imitation of the Buddhists, used to erect something as a memorial resembling their Skambha, and the poor in a similar manner copied them on a reduced scale, and afterwards the miniature memorials of the poor Hindus became a new addition to the Skambha.
>
> One of the names of the Buddhist Stupas (memorial topes) is Dhâtu-garbha, that is, "metal-wombed". Within the Dhatu-garbha, in small cases made of stone, shaped like the present Shalagrama, used to be preserved the ashes, bones, and other remains of the distinguished Buddhist Bhikshus, along with gold, silver, and other metals. The Shalagrama-Shilas are natural stones resembling in form these artificially-cut stone-cases of the Buddhist Dhatu-garbha, and thus being first worshipped by the Buddhists, gradually got into Vaishnavism, like many other forms of Buddhistic worship that found their way into Hinduism. On the banks of the Narmadâ and in Nepal, the Buddhistic influence lasted longer than in other parts of India; and the remarkable coincidence that the Narmadeshvara Shiva-Linga, found on the banks of the Narmadâ and hence so called, and the Shalagrama-Shilas of Nepal are given preference to by the Hindus to those found elsewhere in India is a fact that ought to be considered with respect to this point of contention.
>
> The explanation of the Shalagrama-Shila as a phallic emblem was an imaginary invention and, from the very beginning, beside the mark. The explanation of the Shiva-Linga as a phallic emblem was brought forward by the most thoughtless, and was forthcoming in India in her most degraded times, those of the downfall of Buddhism. The filthiest Tântrika literature of Buddhism of those times is yet largely found and practiced in Nepal and Tibet.

The Stambha or sacrificial post became representative of Brahman (Shiva) as from all angles around it, it looks the same. Whatever the initial reasons, the symbol has evolved into a representation of the Godhead. The other parts of your question are nonsense.

Comment: Ya both Mr Gustav and Swami Vivekananda are no doubt right about there knowledge of Shiva Linga worship that has flowed down the river of time from a place of its true origin a place where realization was the reality.