# Shiva Linga realization within the body

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

The Shiva Linga is generally symbolized in stone as an external object of worship. Can the true Shiva Linga be seen within the body of man via the minds' eye?

Comment: See [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18837/what-are-the-three-shivalingas-itara-bana-and-swayambhu-mentioned-in-some-ag). So Shiva Lingas exist in three centres of the body. But obviously in the subtle form so they can not be seen with normal eyes.

Comment: Ya, it can only be seen with the eye that is able to look within. This Inner Shiva linga that is seen in the subtle body, in you say 3 locations is it not the one Shiva Linga in various stages of its unfoldment.