# Can someone please list some Linga shaped mountains/hills? What are their stories?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam, india

To give an example, here are 2 Linga peaks - Kailash (which is associated as abode of Lord Shiva) and the birthplace of Hanumanji, Anjaneri

[image]

[image]

How many more mountains and hills have this kind of shape or peak? Is there a list given in any Hindu scriptures? What is the reason given for other such peaks?

Comment: The following answer is related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18840

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rickross !! I was actually also looking at power of Narmedeshwar Shivling earlier today

Comment: Yes, some of those hills are external Shiva Lingas (Itara etc) as mentioned in that answer

Answer (score 5):

There is a peak in Himalaya mountain region of India which is called as [**Shivling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivling_(mountain)) (mountain).

[image]

Shivling is a mountain at tapovan in the **Gangotri Group of peaks in the western Garhwal Himalaya, near the snout of the Gangotri Glacier.** It lies in the northern Indian state of Uttarakhand, 6 kilometres (4 mi) south of the Hindu holy site of Gaumukh (the source of the Bhagirathi River).Its name refers to its status as a sacred symbol -Shiva Linga.

---

Another of the mountain peak which is of shape like Shiva-Linaga is  located near Dobbaspet, in Bengaluru Rural district India.  The mountain peak is called [**Shivagange mountain peak**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivagange)   and is 9 km from the town of Tumakuru and 54 km from Bengaluru.

**This sacred mountain is shaped as a shivalinga** and a spring flows near locally called "Ganga", thereby giving the place its name. It is also known as Dakshina Kashi (Kashi of the South) and has various temples such as Gangadhareshwara temple, Sri Honnammadevi Temple, Olakal Teertha, Nandi Statue, Patalagang Sharadambe temple and several theerthas such as Agasthya theertha, Kanva theertha, Kapila theertha, Pathala Gange

[image]

---

Image source - Wikipedia

Comment: Although not much information is avaliable about the history of the mountain on internet so "why" question is currently unanswered but I will try to search more and will try to update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I remember this one! It would be great to have a complete list if that is possible

Comment: In this shivagange temple, ghee offered as abhisekha turns into butter. See https://www.myspiritualtreasure.com/2017/08/ghee-offered-as-abhisheka-to-lord-shiva.html

Comment: @R.Kaushik - yes added one more peak from south India in answer. There could be  lots of such small hills that are similarely shaped like a linge might be present in India. but its not possible to list them all. There is one small mountain in Maharashtra called as "Lingoba" mountain , such  regional hills are not much known outside district or state and also not much visited. So it will be better if you edit the question and instead of asking "how many are there" simply ask about a possible  list without the need of counting .

Comment: @GIRIBLR - We both found same mountain at same time.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes. I have visited this place several times. It is a quiet place to meditate. There is also a water body in the hill which turns cold in summer and hot in winter.

Comment: @GIRIBLR- Oh it's really nice you visited the place. The spring of water is called Ganga and so the name.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks for updating your answer. This is all very interesting!! I will change the question now to something more appropriate as you've said :) I've never heard of Lingoba :o

Comment: @GIRIBLR Thanks!!